# Agregar arrays a un array en una posicion espeficica

Tags: javascript, jquery

lo que quiero hacer es agregar un array a otro en una posicion especifica, pero no se como hacerlo, lo intente con esta forma

```
datos = new Array();
$('#tabla tbody tr').each(function()
{
    dato01_id = $(this).find("td:nth-child(2)").text();
    dato02 = $(this).find("td:nth-child(2)").text();
    dato03 = $(this).find("td:nth-child(2)").text();
    ref01 = $(this).find("td:nth-child(2)").text();
    ref02 = $(this).find("td:nth-child(2)").text();
    ref03 = $(this).find("td:nth-child(2)").text();

    datos[dato01_id] = {
        "dato02" : dato02,
        "dato03" : dato03,
        "refs" : []
    };
    $('#tabla tbody tr').each(function()
    {
        dato01_id_02 = $(this).find("td:nth-child(2)").text();
        if ( dato01_id == dato01_id_02 )
        {
            (datos[dato01_id]['refs']).push({
                "ref01" : ref01,
                "ref02" : ref02,
                "ref03" : ref03
            });
        }
    });

});
```

Queriendo que salga asi

```
"dato01_id" : {
            "dato02": "Dato02",
            "dato03": "Dato03",
            "refs": [
                {
                    "ref01": "Ref01",
                    "ref02": "Ref02",
                    "ref03": "Ref03"
                },
                {
                    "ref01": "Ref01",
                    "ref02": "Ref02",
                    "ref03": "Ref03"
                },
                .
                .
                .
            ]
        }
```

Me sale de esa forma pero en "refs" agrega solo el ultimo registro y este se repite.
La función principal seria esta para agregar un array en otra en una posición especifica

```
if ( dato01_id == dato01_id_02 )
        {
            (datos[dato01_id]['refs']).push({
                "ref01" : ref01,
                "ref02" : ref02,
                "ref03" : ref03
            });
        }
```

Hice otras formas pero aun asi se seguia repitiendo el ultimo registro

Comment: podrias colocar tu estructura html ya que todos los selectores apuntan a lo mismo `td:nth-child(2)`

Comment: Buenas, ya descubri cual era el error, los datos que deberian ser agregados los estoy tomando del primer each y no del segundo ciclo each, por eso salian repetidos los datos. Gracias igualmente

Answer (score 0):

podes usar el método splice para agregar elementos en un array en una posición especifica. el primer parámetro es el indice donde vas a ubicar los nuevos elementos, el segundo parámetro son los elementos que querés eliminar del array original (en este ejemplo: 0), y por ultimo agregas los elementos que quieras añadir. Saludos!

```js
var dogs = ['Bulldog', 'Beagle', 'Labrador'];

dogs.splice(2, 0, 'Pug', 'Boxer');                        

console.log(dogs);  //salida: ["Bulldog", "Beagle", "Pug", "Boxer", "Labrador"]
```

Comment: Lo intente de esa forma pero aun sigue igual, salen datos repetidos.
El codigo que utilize es este: `datos[dato01_id]['refs'].splice(cont,0,datos_agregar) ` La variable cont es un contador, buscare otro metodo para agregar, gracias